# My android homescreen widget appears, but is not updating

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I already found others questions similar to mine, but could not find the solution. I have a custom widget with simple `TextView` and also a configuration `Activity`. Problem is:

1. When widget is added to homescreen, configurations activity appears, but `onUpdate()` method of `AppWidgetProvider` runs immediately, as soon as configuration activity is created. It should run after configuration activity is closed by pressing OK button.
2. Even if `onUpdate()` method run on configuration activity start (according to Toast in the method,showing proper data for textview), the TextView remains still not updated.
3. Even if android:updatePeriodMillis is set to 1000ms, onUpdate method run only once - when configuration activity starts.
4. When I add the widget to my homescreen and then restart phone, the widget's TextView is finally updated with proper time, but only once.

Many users have been reporting similar problems on recent android versions, like 4.4. Is there any final solution for this bad behavior?

Here are my files - Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="incredible.riskofrain.app">

<application android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/main_icon">

    <receiver android:name=".RORAppWidgetProvider" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                   android:resource="@xml/ror_appwidget_info" />

    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".RORAppWidgetConfigure">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="incredible.riskofrain.app.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

appwidget_info:

```
android:minWidth="200dp"
android:minHeight="80dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="1000"
android:initialLayout="@layout/ror_appwidget"
android:configure="incredible.riskofrain.app.RORAppWidgetConfigure"
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
android:widgetCategory="home_screen"   >
```

AppWidgetProvider:

```
public class RORAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String time = "" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+ ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);


        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.ror_appwidget);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.textview, time);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            Toast.makeText(context, "onUpdate " + time + " " + appWidgetId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }}
```

AppWidgetConfigure:

```
public class RORAppWidgetConfigure extends Activity {

int appWidgetId; Button button; AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
RemoteViews views;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(R.layout.ror_configure);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        appWidgetId = extras.getInt(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),  R.layout.ror_appwidget);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

            Intent resultValue = new Intent();
            resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);

            Toast.makeText(getApplication().getApplicationContext(), "Configure, ID: - " + appWidgetId+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            finish();

        }
    });

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in documentation, probably this is the problem:

> **public int updatePeriodMillis**
>   Added in API level 3
>   How often, in milliseconds, that this AppWidget wants to be updated. The AppWidget manager may place a limit on how often a AppWidget is updated.
>   This field corresponds to the android:updatePeriodMillis attribute in the AppWidget meta-data file.
>   **Note: Updates requested with updatePeriodMillis will not be delivered more than once every 30 minutes.**

---

I also found that there is a huge bug in android framework making configuration activity useless: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3696

Answer (score 0):

you can update Widget using **broasdcast Receiver** ..

check this link:

[Reference Link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/04/introducing-home-screen-widgets-and.html)

```
<!-- Broadcast Receiver that will process AppWidget updates -->
<receiver android:name=".WordWidget" android:label="@string/widget_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget_word" />
</receiver>
```

i hope its useful to you..